# Continue name and numbering

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to add photos to existing photo folder. If my last photo in the folder is photo 56.jpg and I want to add 10 more new photos and want them to continue name and numbering like photo 57.jpg ; photo 58.jpg so on....

Can some one help with a batch file for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off &SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "photofolder=photos"
SET "newfolder=newphotos"

FOR %%a IN ("%photofolder%\Photo *.jpg") DO (
    FOR /f "tokens=2" %%b IN ("%%~na") DO IF %%b gtr !hi! SET /a hi=%%b
)
FOR %%a IN ("%newfolder%\*.jpg") DO (
    SET /a hi+=1
    COPY "%%~fa" "%photofolder%\Photo !hi!%%~xa"
)
```